# Medical Linac MeV vs MV

Tags: medical-physics

I am currently doing a project on medical linear accelerators, and there's one thing I am having trouble understanding. Why is the electron beam energy measured in MeV, but the x-ray energy is measured in MV? Thanks!

Edit: this line from Wikipedia sort of answers my question, "The voltage in this case refers to the voltage used to accelerate electrons in the linear accelerator and indicates the maximum possible energy of the photons which are subsequently produced" but the source they got this from says, "The bremsstrahlung spectrum produced in a given X ray target depends on the kinetic energy of the incident electron as well as on the thickness and atomic number Z of the target."

To clarify, the maximum energy of the photon beam is determined by the voltage used to accelerate the electrons, but the energy of the photon beam is determined by the kinetic energy of the incident electrons and the target. Is this correct?

Comment: Many of us get sloppy distinguishing between MeV and MV. That’s all.

Comment: What have you done so far to figure this out?

Comment: Possibly useful [Videos by Don Lincoln](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS): 48-50, 52, 53, 55, and 61.

Comment: "medical linear accelerators" ... just being curios: are you referring to C^{4-} beams?

Comment: @user121330 Hi, thanks for the comment. Mostly I have been reading chapter 5 from the IAEA radiation oncology handbook which I found online here: https://www-pub.iaea.org/MTCD/Publications/PDF/Pub1196_web.pdf. I am trying to understand the basics of how linacs work but am getting confused when, for example, the difference between high vs low energy linacs are reported in MV, but the electron beam energy is in MeV.

Comment: @mmesser314 thanks, I will check those out!

Answer (score 1):

Since the x-ray beam is polychromatic, it doesn't really make sense to use a single energy value (eV) to refer to the beam.  The convention is to use the accelerating voltage to describe the x-ray beam.

Sometimes when you see an x-ray beam described in terms of eV, it often refers to the mean or peak energy of the x-ray spectrum.

The actual x-ray spectrum will be determined by the energy of the accelerated electron beam, the target material, and the target thickness.